# How to sum all inputs values by formula

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few products that hold price,quantity and price incrase and need to show total of all of them
How can i sum total of all inputs with formula (price + increase) * quantity , no matter with input value is change ?

Some of them also may be empty with no values

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  
  var total = 0;
  var quantity = 0;
  var price = 0;
  var increase = 0
  
  $.each($('input'), function(key, value){
    if($(this).hasClass('quantity')){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        quantity = 0;
      }else{
        quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
      }  
    }
    
    if($(this).hasClass('price')){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        price = 0;
      }else{
        price = parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
      
    }
    
    if($(this).hasClass('increase')){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        increase = 0;
      }else{
        increase = parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
      
    }
    
    
    
    total += (price + increase) * quantity;
    
    
  });
  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="quantity" name="product[19234]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
<input class="price" name="product[19234]['price']" type="text" value="100 ">
<input class="increase" name="product[19234]['increase']" type="text" value="">

<br>
 
<input class="quantity" name="product[192]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
<input class="price" name="product[192]['price']" type="text" value="100">
<input class="increase" name="product[192]['increase']" type="text" value="">

<br>

<input class="quantity" name="product[234]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
<input class="price" name="product[234]['price']" type="text" value="100">
<input class="increase" name="product[234]['increase']" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give some `outer` div and then use that as selector to separate each rows then using `.find()` to get each input values and perform calculation.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var total = 0;
  //loop through div
  $('div.outer').each(function() {
    //get values 
    var quantity = ($(this).find('.quantity').val() != "") ? parseInt($(this).find('.quantity').val()) : 0;
    var price = ($(this).find('.price').val() != "") ? parseInt($(this).find('.price').val()) : 0;
    var increase = ($(this).find('.increase').val() != "") ? parseInt($(this).find('.increase').val()) : 0;
    total += (price + increase) * quantity;
  });
  $("p#total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--dive some outer div to separate each row-->
<div class="outer">
  <input class="quantity" name="product[19234]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
  <input class="price" name="product[19234]['price']" type="text" value="100 ">
  <input class="increase" name="product[19234]['increase']" type="text" value="">
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <input class="quantity" name="product[192]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
  <input class="price" name="product[192]['price']" type="text" value="100">
  <input class="increase" name="product[192]['increase']" type="text" value="">
  <div>
    <br>
    <div class="outer">
      <input class="quantity" name="product[234]['quantity']" type="text" value="1">
      <input class="price" name="product[234]['price']" type="text" value="100">
      <input class="increase" name="product[234]['increase']" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <p id="total"></p>
```